# Azure AD SQL Authentication giving Network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, x509certificate

I am attempting to connect to Azure SQL from a webapi service running on IIS.  If I use a connection string with user id and password it works fine.

When I use connection string builder using an access token generated by sending ClientAssertionCertificate to Azure AD, I get the connection error above.

When I create the same code in a Console Application and run it on the same VM as the IIS server, it works fine.

I thought this might be related to permissions since it works in the Console Application.  I tried changing the identity used by DefaultAppPool but that did not work.

```
string accessToken = TokenFactory.GetAccessToken();

var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder["Data Source"] = $"tcp:{dbServer}.database.windows.net,1433";
builder["Initial Catalog"] = dbName;
builder["Connect Timeout"] = 30;
builder["Persist Security Info"] = false;
builder["TrustServerCertificate"] = false;
builder["Encrypt"] = true;
builder["MultipleActiveResultSets"] = true;

var con = new SqlConnection(builder.ToString());
con.AccessToken = accessToken;

// attempting to use the con from the SqlConnecti
CompanyService _cs = new CompanyService(con);
var company = _cs.GetCompany(1);

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { teststring = accessToken } );
```

Comment: As it works in console application, maybe it's you configured different outbound IP for this site in IIS, which is not allowed for Azure SQL. You can check it first. If no luck, please share the code about how you get access token.

Comment: Do you have a chance to take a look at my previous comment?